# Template defined in directive present in DOM but not displaying

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and just now completed the Angular intro course from CodeSchool mentioned on the Angular homepage. I am trying to follow their example of creating a directive that contains a template and controller, because it makes the index.html very clean.

The problem is however that when I load the index.html page and click the submit button nothing happens, so it seems like the ng-submit is not working. However, when I don't use a template and put the code from login.html directly in index.html with a ng-controller directive it is working fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

index.html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body ng-app="plunker">
  <login-page></login-page>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('loginPage', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/login.html',
    controllerAs: 'login',
    controller: function() {
      var login = this;
      login.display = true;
      login.doLogin = function() {
        console.log('login');
      }
    }
  };
});
```

login.html

```
<form ng-submit="login.doLogin()">
  <input type="text" id="input-user" placeholder="email" />
  <input type="password" id="input-pass"placeholder="password" />
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the browser console? Have you tried to remove the `/` from your templateUrl? If your template is in the same folder as `app.js` this should work: `templateUrl: 'login.html'`.

Comment: Hi Awolf, thanks for your reply. There are no messages in the console and when I inspect the DOM I do see the template there. It is just that the ng-submit does not seems to call the login.doLogin() function.

Comment: Have you checked if the directive controller gets executed? Just add a `console.log(...)` in the controller to see if its runs.

Comment: How do you serve the app? Do you have a local webserver like [`serve`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) running? If not that's probably your problem. It's required for the template of your directive.

Comment: Hi Awolf, yeah I am serving from Apache so that should not be the problem. It is working now and to be honest I don't know what I did to make it work, but just so you know now it is working both with '/login.html' and 'login.html' so that was not the issue either. Very strange! Since you posted to the comments I cannot accept your answer for responding first, so I will upvote you and accept mofojed's answer to thank you both for your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out AWolf, templateUrl should be "login.html", not "/login.html".

Also a minor type with a space missing before placeholder=, but that shouldn't cause any problems:

```
<input type="password" id="input-pass"placeholder="password" />
```

Otherwise this should be working. I've created a plunkr demonstrating it's working: http://plnkr.co/edit/yT35qkl7K5ewiDl31DMK?p=preview

Comment: Hi mofojed, as I wrote to Awolf, the issue was not with the prefix slash (I saw the template already injected into the DOM), nor with the placeholder issue since that was just a mistake I made when sanitizing before posting here. Anyway it's working now, so I guess I must have had a little typo somewhere... Thanks for your efforts!